# Opening file at each iteration in a loop PYTHON

Tags: python, loops, file, iteration, txt

I have a loop:

```
for i in range(202,293):
*excetution of a certain code*
```

At each execution the program returns two arrays and I want to save these outputs for each iteration separately.
I cant write :

```
file1 = open("Failed_sources.txt","a")
file1.write("source = GCC0" ,i)
file1.close()
```

because that would just modify the .txt file, while I want a new one each time.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
for i in range(202,293):
    with open(f"Failed_sorces{str(i)}.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(f"source = GCC0, {str(1)}")
```